# Buffer cannot be null error when opening excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, buffer, excellibrary

I am using excel Library to open a spread Sheet and read its contents, I am using this library over the interop library as the interop library causes issues on the server machine i hope to host on.

https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

```
using ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet;

Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(excelFileName); //FilePath
Workbook book = Workbook.Load(fileStream); //Exception thrown
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
```

When running the code, you can see the file stream load:

[image]

When i step to next line i get the exception. Buffer cannot be null.

[image]

After the exception the stream reader becomes canRead false:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As @pomster pointed out, the problem most times here is:

> The XLS file being of type "5.0/95" instead of "97-2003"

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET Code:

```
Public Function importSheet(fileName As String) As Boolean
  Dim fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName)        
  Dim book = ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Workbook.Load(fileStream)
  Dim sheet = book.Worksheets(0)

  'TO DO
  Return True
End Function
```

Look for folder's permission.

When System.IO library has many Exceptions, look read/write folder's and files permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **file name**, not stream to method `Workbook.Load`, see example in own [link](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/):

```
string file = "C:\\newdoc.xls";
// open xls file
Workbook book = Workbook.Load(file);
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
```

If there is an overload for it, then you have to ask library author for assistance (it looks like a bug).

Comment: .Load(Path) Or .Load(filestream) Both give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple program and I dont get this Exception,

Can you check you Excel file ? may be it is corrupt.

you can make a simple program that is just opening this application ?

```
string excelFileName = "";
        excelFileName = @"E:\Innovation\PAKISTAN.xls";
        Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(excelFileName); //FilePath
        Workbook book = Workbook.Load(fileStream); //Exception thrown
        Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
```

Comment: My Excels are Microsoft Excel 5.0/95 Workbook, .xls if i save them as Microsoft Excel 97-2003, .xls it looks to work

Comment: the issue is already [reported](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/issues/detail?id=94&q=buffer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20ReportedBy%20Owner%20Summary%20Opened)

Answer (score -1):

You need the `@` symbol at the front of your path filename.

Try

```
excelFileName = string.Format(@"{0}",excelFileName);
```